# How can I use the second line in the foreach output as a Uri in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, indexing, foreach, null

I got a foreach in C#

```cs
foreach (string info in imgInfo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(info);
}
```

It outputs (starts with "https: ends with s") First and Last are actually null

```
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTNj5E5-dl1C1k7n2dFs0NKhjKGBAgwiIUV_3KhbRjSeei295HzIWU2OMRN1Q&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtF6P0ucV3jEofG7AJ99cVfLq-IV9KVYR-JHu4DWYOdggARh3MuV2bwD-7FA&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTxznofulAcFIEairkGIa43gF3nxnYczJ6n1KPuLKxFbbnmt2d8077wktn3-HQ&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQjAr-eMc0iejN6P9A1Eh3_rHn53M_OV6ZyjFLDWsJp5VcgJ8iA2EYXJ9B6Ig&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTuuyLDKGuWWsXH0sOaJWSqx1k5oD1N1YdjTNWhkXvekYsV7Gm0mWyptFDdMw&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxO6YZGkVPINj9iRe75iO1R2UbE0ElKVWpuUnZYYCJoVj9L8_hzzNY7mBmJTI&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSfqGQ2QgpUflYLUFMi3IlkQ0ysF8gsgtE-m6mBbZ1rA2QlGZ7VYfg00OJIXg&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQu_nqlO2fZ6PD0n05B6A4sSlu9Vyrxtw2gGoKkFzyA0DhsKCJ9RSoco-E93A&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRh9OZGExey9Dof6uRU9XgCSIYBS5eX5r2ascC99CmOhgW7h9Gk0K1e93nBIw&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOORDumK13-ey0KJ6q3_eHIjaQE_Vma9ORew4qvj1txCRfP5SH7FmtlJOhuA&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR7cTlcOLwMmDJgu7wWmri5TxkxkbVtHQbm0syHQoq0LOFam7DooGbIYcx39Q&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS4X10zxyaNftXVaibHUyPRSpRmyp4QdpQWc57WUQi2MRB1o3mpxtjh0GT3TEA&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS8nCYaetuPTsMyEW9GJjU0C4gzj49CgnPt5e0PCe2Zj9tlS6YBMjiV-tdULQ&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ6HH69-ZYs3925KatdjbvhabDCt36Dj0WzzQePOMpSTP_9ZF0Sy7mfXHsOf9E&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSECCOssnbTgFXPs7QLo80CD7gOc6JRw5nboEhuTYOKrKZyibUb6Xsg-CoOwGk&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcStUWZQZzkeLjFLtUMFMlpl5Qy0nuTW5V5vRNcMCzYsSlzfnHWl34YKbZ27tA&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSOLgAGaDYprRUVquHS84XpLSTlWjB6tdoE8kUG1Rz6KplehANq_rIBoOo4rp4&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYqXQRxA-N3jy1lZB1sqAaaGA2lCiSwy9OXx3i_600q0HV6tIi5AxF43TRDP8&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMvv9pZFfCVfOJ3NOm50YIYKcoeNtwqfScdxKk5UocwhWdvmIGoyu1GCuvLwc&amp;s"
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSCu2m8t9ryLSsUK7Dl9ehQNuYRgZlGaWeEE81Sp63yDEvjqYJpo1Ch78y955M&amp;s"
"https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=de&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjt8sT6kvnuAhUmposKHYfNAeYQv5YECFg"
"https://www.google.com/intl/de_de/policies/privacy/"
"https://www.google.com/intl/de_de/policies/terms/"
```

How can I use the second (3rd, 4th, or 5th, etc.) value as a Uri?
I think I have to remove null values first. I tried info.Remove(null) but it doesn't work and info.IndexOf(2) and it doesn't work either.

I actually want to use the first 5 URLs to be the Uri for Button Image Source

```
button1.Content = new Image
{

    //first url from info as New Uri
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(info))

};
button2.Content = new Image
{

    //second url from info as new Uri
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(info))

};
```

button3, button4, button5

Comment: Show your code, please. Where you get links?

Comment: https://github.com/zitron16/ImagesForPowerPoint/blob/master/ImagesForPowerPoint/MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: `foreach (string info in imgInfo.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand what exactly you want to have as an end result.
Do you want a list of individual strings, where each string is one address?
If yes, then this code will work, although it is not elegant or efficient...just the first thing that came to my mind.

```
        List<string> uriResult = new List<string>();

        foreach (string s in info.Split("https"))
        {
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                uriResult.Add("https" + s);
        }
```

Greets, Paco